# How to pass multiple param values for the same key to GET with Postman

Tags: get, postman

I'm new to Postman and APIs in general. I have a need to pass multiple param values for the same key to a GET with Postman.

I want the end result to be a listing of all "features" corresponding to the param values passed to the GET call for the key "id".

I've researched and tried every permutation found on SO and other boards with zero luck.  I even tried the same variations using POST with even worse results.  So....posting here in hopes that someone can help.

Here's what I've tried so far:

GET https://URL/api/feature?id=SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo

Returns the expected feature

GET https://URL/api/feature?id=MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw

Returns the expected feature

GET https://URL/api/feature?id=SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo&id=MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw

Returns just the feature associated with SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo

GET https://URL/api/feature?id[]=SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo&id[]=MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw

Returns ALL features

GET https://URL/api/feature?where={"id":["SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo","MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw"]}

Returns ALL features

Is what I'm doing possible?  If so, I'd appreciate suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Multiple values to the same key can only be achieved by the array method, which you have already tried `GET https://URL/api/feature?id[]=SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo&id[]=MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw`

Comment: I think you don't completely understand how GET params work: in general, one param has 1 value. If you want to use multiple values, use arrays

Comment: Thx folks.  I tried an array (I think) and it still failed.  Do you have an example on how to do this that I could work with?

Answer (score 4):

Put in the address bar the endpoint.

Put in Params tab required values:

```
KEY           VALUE
id[]          SdxApTWLym1n3D5-hR-QOvwaklo
id[]          MzqDzjNch3vZ4c9R54I5AtDgwCw
```

Run the request in the POSTMAN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send two param value in postman just create only two params and two values same you want in Params column.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I am looking for ... but now how to specify the "2" and "3" values from a single postman array/variable defined in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could try arrays as have been advised.

An example is:

```
KEY        VALUE
id         [{"column1":"value1"},{"column2":"value2"}]
```

or

```
KEY        VALUE
id         [{"column1":"value1","column2":"value2"},{"column3":"value3","column4":"value4"}]
```

API should be capable of processing such structures.