# Postman - How the send the same request with different param values

Tags: json, node.js, rest, api, postman

I created a simple API and I want to test the responses for requests with different parameter values.
Is there a way to send the same request with different parameter values without sending a different request for every combination of param values?

Comment: No, once a HTTP request is sent it's gone, it can't be reused.

Comment: You can try   postman collections for multiple request  Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZKoBQ1HpKw

Comment: You could use Postman for this purpose:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638364/how-to-pass-multiple-param-values-for-the-same-key-to-get-with-postman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your parameter values as [environment variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments), and then use them in the parameter text editor with this syntax `{{variableName}}`.

To update the environment variable values, you can either use the [variables editor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments#editing-an-active-environment) or set the value in a [pre-request script](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts) with this syntax `pm.environment.set("variableName", variableValue)`.

In this way, you can send the same request with different parameter values.

Comment: The link has been changed. Here is the link for [pre-request-script](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre-request-scripts/)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that, every HTTP request using once .

any change of parameter that's mean new http request