# How to execute the same GET request using multiple data in postman?

Tags: get, postman

I have request as below:

```
somehost:port/sometext?type={{type}}
```

I want to replace the `{{type}}` by three different values.

How do I implement it using postman scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman - How the send the same request with different param values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830362/postman-how-the-send-the-same-request-with-different-param-values)

Comment: Have you tried with postman runner ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried using the postman runner, but I want the data to be passed only to one particular request which is causing problem when using newman -d command. In newman, it increases the iteration as per the count of data not just for the targeted test but also for the complete collection.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use postman runner with a data (csv or json) file with the values of "type", and in runner select collection, then the data file and enter the iterations as required.

[Refer the documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/starting-a-collection-run/#data)